# Algebra Normal Subroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question about normal subgroups of index $2$:

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of index $2$, is there anything that we can say about $G$?

Comment: Probably not much, unless you know something more about $H$ and $G$.

Comment: $G$ has even order, and can only be simple if $H$ is the identity - this is not much, but I don't see much else that could be said in general.

Comment: ...if $\,G\,$ is finite, of course....

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is Abelian you can build all $G$'s using 2nd cohomology group $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2,H)$.

If $H$ is non-Abelian you can figure out by  $H^3(\mathbb{Z}_2,Z(H))$ wheter there is such $G$.

For details see K.Brown, Cohomology of Groups.